# Passing variables into the names_glue parameter of tidyr::pivot_wider

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyeval, r-glue

Here's some silly data that we pivot wider, using two names:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
    food = c('banana','banana','banana','banana','cheese','cheese','cheese','cheese'),
    binary = c(rep(c('yes','no'), 4)),
    car = c('toyota','subaru','mazda','skoda','toyota','subaru','mazda','skoda'),
    fun = c(2,4,3,6,2,4,2,3))

df %>%
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = food,
        names_from = c(car, binary),
        values_from = fun)
```

If we want to change the format of the new variable names, e.g., from `toyota_yes` to `yes_toyota`, we use the `names_glue` argument:

```
df %>%
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = food,
        names_from = c(car, binary),
        names_glue = "{binary}_{car}",
        values_from = fun)
```

The issue I'm facing is finding the correct syntax to pass variable names to the `names_glue` parameter. It's easy to pass variables to `names_from`, e.g.:

```
var1 <- 'car'
var2 <- 'binary'
df %>%
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = food,
        names_from = c(var1, var2),
        values_from = fun)
```

But we can't directly do that with `names_glue`:

```
df %>%
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = food,
        names_from = c(var1, var2),
        names_glue = "{var1}_{var2}",
        values_from = fun)
```

> Error: Column names `car_binary`, `car_binary`, and `car_binary` must not be duplicated.

Presumably it's evaluating the variable and just passing the resulting string (i.e., 'car' or 'binary') into the glue function. I have played around with some things I would normally use for tidy evaluation (`!!sym(...)`, etc.) but haven't got anything to work. Desired output is the following, using variables for the `names_glue` parameter:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  food   yes_toyota no_subaru yes_mazda no_skoda
  <fct>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 banana          2         4         3        6
2 cheese          2         4         2        3
```

[Here is the commit that added the names_glue parameter to pivot_wider -- although I can't really figure out how to troubleshoot with this.](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/commit/e74748fca8737f7c632b22a8a703bc1779261e17)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sprtinf`/`paste0` to construct the string :

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = food,
    names_from = c(var1, var2),
    names_glue = sprintf('{%s}_{%s}', var2, var1),
    values_from = fun)

#  food   yes_toyota no_subaru yes_mazda no_skoda
#  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 banana          2         4         3        6
#2 cheese          2         4         2        3
```

Answer (score 4):

We can create the pattern with `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     pivot_wider(
         id_cols = food,
         names_from = c(var1, var2),
         names_glue = glue::glue("{[var1]}_{[var2]}", .open = '[', .close = ']'),
         values_from = fun)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  food   toyota_yes subaru_no mazda_yes skoda_no
#  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 banana          2         4         3        6
#2 cheese          2         4         2        3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was available at the time of posting, but the [tidyr documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) suggests you can just pass this `"{var1}_{var2}"` syntax directly to `names_glue` these days (without having to define any variables outside the dataframe either) and it seems to be working for me!